# Миграция в readthedocs (python)

Tags: django, python-2.x, миграция

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема при миграции по [мануалу](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

При исполнение команды:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Выдает следующую ошибку:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
 execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/home/aldnoahzero/rtd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/aldnoahzero/rtd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/home/aldnoahzero/rtd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/home/aldnoahzero/rtd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/home/aldnoahzero/rtd/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/aldnoahzero/rtd/checkouts/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from readthedocs.worker import app  # noqa
File "/home/aldnoahzero/rtd/checkouts/readthedocs.org/readthedocs/worker.py", line 7, in <module>
from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named celery
```

Код файла manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "readthedocs.settings.dev")
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

До этого ни разу не использовал миграцию с помощью питона, да и вообще не работал с ним. В чем может быть проблема? Почему не проходит миграция.

Установлен MySQL локально, но в нём ничего не создавал из БД, в мануале, вроде, ничего про это не было сказано.

Версия питона: 2.7.12

Comment: Раз ошибка `ImportError: No module named celery` про отсутствующий модуль, то почему бы не попробовать его установить?

Comment: @gil9red вот же блин. Я чет даже не понял, что это отдельный модуль. 
Пошел ставить. Спасибо. ) Оформишь как отдельный ответ или удалить этот глупый вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы `ImportError: No module named celery` будет ручная установка модуля [celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/celery).

Например: `pip install Celery`